# How to measure time taken for a DB fetch in java

Tags: java, performance, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to find the time taken for a DB fetch from my java servlet. The Db fetch should ideally return around 1K rows. The function to fetch is as follows.

```
ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(select xxxx from xxxx);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) 
    {
        rs.getString(1);
    }
```

I need only the time for DB call/fetch (ie. i do not need the time taken for getting the connection from the pool, or the time taken for parsing through the data etc.)

If i need to find the time taken for the fetch alone which among the below is the right approach.
first approach:

```
  ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(select xxxx from xxxx);
int initialTime=getTime();
rs = ps.executeQuery();
int finalTime=getTime();
while (rs.next()) 
    {
        rs.getString(1);
    }
System.out.println("Time taken="+ finalTime - initialTime);
```

second approach:

```
 ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(select xxxx from xxxx);
int initialTime=getTime();
rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) 
    {
        rs.getString(1);
    }
int finalTime=getTime();
System.out.println("Time taken="+ finalTime - initialTime);
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You will have to time both - there's not really any way to separate the two. The first approach doesn't read any data from the DB - it just opens a cursor. You could loop and not call `getXXX` at all.

Comment: Thanks. I think my understanding of resultset was nt right.

Answer (score 0):

javamelody is a library that lets you measure things like query times, memory usage, etc.

https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/